Why does the instantaneous force decrease in this electromagnet and iron piece setup?
This is related to a previous question In which direction does the iron piece experience force in this electromagnet setup?
Given an Initial Setup of a fixed electromagnet and a vertically movable iron piece  when the electromagnet is energized, the iron piece moves vertically and the final state the system achieves is as follows: 
Now, My understanding from the answers is as follows: As the iron piece moves 'up' more and more magnetic lines of force pass through the point of contact b/w electromagnet and iron piece (denoted by 'Path A') than the ends of the electromagnet (denoted by 'Path B') below: 
Now here are a few doubts I have:
Query 1: As the iron piece move upwards will the force with which the electromagnet pulls increase, decrease or remain constant. The answer (given to me) to this seems to be that it would decrease quadratically as the it moves upwards. But I am unclear why?
The number of field lines passing through Path B will definitely exert an upwards pull on the iron piece. But, won't the field lines passing through Path A also exert an upwards pull? If not can someone explain why so? I mean Path A should also exert an upwards pull as it shortens the Path A b/w electromagnet and iron piece. So what is wrong with this reasoning?
Can someone please explain it conceptually?
EDIT: Just to reiterate, I am not asking about the end equilibrium state, but regarding the instantaneous force at any point in time and how it changes as the iron piece moves in the vertical axis?

This is probably a poor attempt at an explanation, but here goes.
The important thing to remember is that the iron's permeability is about 1,000 times better than air. You can consider this to be the magnetic equivalent of resistance in an electrical circuit.

Figure 1. The magnetic circuit.
Looking at your third image, the flux through the orange 'B' lines would effectively be zero as there is a much easier path through the magnetic circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 2. Modelling the two positions as an electrical circuit.
It should be clear from Figure 2 that the overall circuit resistance is lower in (b) as there is less series resistance between the voltage source terminals. That means that more current will flow in (b) than in (a).
In the magnetic circuit more flux will flow when the magnetic circuit path length is minimised. This will occur when the horizontal section of the armature is in line with the fixed pole pieces. If the armature is free to move it should pull into that position (ignoring the effect of gravity).

thanks. I understand everything you said and agree about the analogy and preferred path (I wrote the same in Q itself). But it simply doesn't answer the Q about how the 'pull force' changes as the armature moves and why so..

Are you familiar with stepper motors? How do they pull into position? Why?

No. My background is not in Electrical Engg. And even it were, in my humble opinion I would still like to know answer from first principles and concepts.. absolute basics/foundations..

Given a constant current, the stored energy in the inductor is
half the inductance times the square of the current.   The reason
that the motion of the coil achieves the final state, is that
work is done (by the magnetic field) in moving to that position.
The reason that the final position is stable, is that it is
the position that (because it magnetizes less iron) holds the minimum
stored energy; the derivative of stored energy with respect to displacement is zero (derivative vanishes at a minimum or maximum value).   It's minimum stored energy because less length of magnetic path is
magnetized, and less volume of iron is magnetized.
The other two iron fingers, if they were moved to contact the lower span, might
ALSO create a local minimum of stored energy; both final positions might be stable, it would take a detailed analysis to determine which initial positions progress to the two equally stable final states.
Measuring inductance versus position would be the easiest way to
experimentally determine those stored-energy-versus-displacement curves.

Thank you but both this an previous answer don't address my doubt in Q: "But, won't the field lines passing through Path A also exert an upwards pull? If not can someone explain why so? I mean Path A should also exert an upwards pull as it shortens the Path A b/w electromagnet and iron piece. So what is wrong with this reasoning?" This was not answered.. and this is the doubt..

And this: "As the iron piece move upwards will the force with which the electromagnet pulls increase, decrease or remain constant. The answer (given to me) to this seems to be that it would decrease quadratically as the it moves upwards. But I am unclear why?"

@TheoryQuest1 There's no net upward pull if the position is that of a local minimum of the inductance.   That's the balance point (unless you add in gravity, or strings, or other forces).

but my question is NOT about final position..! That is not at all what i asked.

@TheoryQuest1 But, the force on the iron is a difficult-to-calculate solution to the magnetic field with odd shaped pole pieces; the curve of vertical displacement versus energy has slopes, and flat spots, probably two flats with a hump between; 'quadratically' just tries to identify a suitable curve to use as an approximate fit.

I understand that exact calculation is difficult. But the qualitative and approximate nature of the force: whether it increases, decreases or remains same (as the iron piece movies up) and why its so happens is not addressed/clear either..? This was the original intent of the Q.. My understanding is that just like to magnets attracted to each other force should increase with decrease in distance.. But no one has clarified why its incorrect?
